# Unit test timeouts in Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, testing, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm trying to test this method checking that the timeouts are correctly set.

```
public HttpClientBuilder getClientBuilderWithTimeouts(final int connT, final int reqT, final int socketT){
    RequestConfig.Builder requestBuilder = RequestConfig.custom();
    requestBuilder = requestBuilder.setConnectTimeout(connT);
    requestBuilder = requestBuilder.setConnectionRequestTimeout(reqT);
    requestBuilder = requestBuilder.setSocketTimeout(socketT);
    HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();     
    clientBuilder.setDefaultRequestConfig(requestBuilder.build());
    return clientBuilder;
}
```

In my unit test though `getParams()` throws `UnsupportedOperationException`. How can I solve this without using an integration test?

```
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
...

@Test
public void testGetClientBuilderWithTimeouts(){

    HttpClientBuilder clBuilder = utils.getClientBuilderWithTimeouts(10, 20, 30);
    CloseableHttpClient testclient = clBuilder.build();

    System.out.println(testclient.getParams().getParameter("http.socket.timeout"));
    System.out.println(testclient.getParams().getParameter("http.connection.timeout"));
    // asserts ..
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to add a `HttpRequestInterceptor` before building the actual client, after getting the client from your utils class (which you want to test).

```
...

import org.apache.http.HttpRequestInterceptor;
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.http.client.protocol.HttpClientContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.apache.http.HttpRequest;
import org.apache.http.HttpException;

... 

builder.addInterceptorFirst(new HttpRequestInterceptor() {

      @Override
      public void process(HttpRequest request, HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException {
        // Get hold of the client context, which holds the request config
        RequestConfig requestConfig = HttpClientContext.adapt(context).getRequestConfig();

        assertEquals(10, requestConfig.getConnectTimeout());
        assertEquals(20, requestConfig.getConnectionRequestTimeout());
        assertEquals(30, requestConfig.getSocketTimeout());
      }
    });
```

Now just do a call to any URL and ignore the exception the client is going to throw in case the request to the URL fails. Since the interceptor is added as first and is a request interceptor, it should be called before the request is attempted, giving you the request config to assert.

Comment: Maybe open a pull-request to apache-httpclient to have the builders expose the values of the configured properties ;)

Comment: This may be the only way that works, but addding `assertEquals` in working code instead of in tests looks.......ugly, sorry. I may go this way but oh, I hope they expose that part.